# Could I use a DC motor in place of a solenoid valve in a simulator?

Tags: dc-motor, proteus, solenoid-valve

I'm doing a project and using Proteus for simulation.

I wanted to use a solenoid valve but couldn't find the component in Proteus.

Could I use a DC motor instead?

Comment: Why don't use an inductor instead?

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely. Motors, once they start to turn generate a back EMF which reduces the current drawn. The solenoid won't.

Instead use an inductor and series resistor. The inductor value you may have to measure. The resistance you can calculate from the voltage and current or power rating.